# How to install dsniff package on termux?

Tags: package-management, android, terminal-emulator, spoofing

I was trying to install `dsniff` package to use dnsspoof.
I tried this command:

```
apt-get install dsniff
```

but I got this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package dsniff
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dsniff` isn’t available in the termux repositories yet; it’s been [requested](https://github.com/termux/termux-root-packages/issues/148) in the “root packages” repo, if everything goes well it will be available there soon (for rooted devices).

Comment: So there is no way to be able to use it now?

Comment: Or at the least is there an alt of it?

Comment: You could always try building it yourself...

Comment: Wait, 'building'?? I will search that.